# How to load a request from file using curl or any other command and issue that request

Tags: linux, http, curl, httprequest

Is there any method available to load the requests from file using curl or any other command and issue that request(GET/POST). Let me explain with example. I have a request stored in file like below -

```
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cookie: somecookie
User-Agent: any user agent
```

I want to pass this file in curl so that the curl issues a request to the endpoint. Is there any other method available to do this ?

Comment: Is your question about this specific file structur? or do you want to know how to store requests in a file?

Comment: @Flo I have a lot of files which contains HTTP requests. I want to curl all these requests which are stored in a file.

Comment: This does not answer my question. In which format are those http requests? if they are NOT in a format curl can read, you need a parser first. 
However, if they are in a format curl can read, it's pretty easy.
Maybe you should do it in 2 steps, parse them first into a file curl can read, and continue.

Comment: @Flo The HTTP requests are in the format which I had specified above.

Answer (score 1):

As already mention in my comment you should split this up in 2 task.

1. Parse your file(s) into valid `curl` parameters

if your files are static and have a common structur, you can keep it simple.
for example you could use `cat` with `sed` and `cut` to extract information like the host:

```
cat testfile | sed '2!d' | cut -d ':' -f2
```

and also your HTTP method:

```
cat testfile | sed '1!d' | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

or your user agent

```
cat testfile | sed '4!d'
```

now

2. Combine and script all arguments

for your example you could do this:

```
curl -X $(cat testfile | sed '1!d' | cut -d ' ' -f1) $(cat testfile | sed '2!d' | cut -d ':' -f2) -H "$(cat testfile | sed '4!d')"
```

(or save each argument as variable and combine them)

which will result in `curl -X GET example.com -H "User-Agent: any user agent"` as provided by your input file.

Answer (score 1):

I once created 'h2c' (headers 2 curl) that converts a HTTP request like that into a curl command line reproducing that request.

You can use it online: https://curl.se/h2c/

Or download the open source script from here: https://github.com/curl/h2c